# JAR file gets modified during execution

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jar

This is after the last unsuccessful run of my program.  I notice that the file size has changed and I can no longer run the Java class for my program:

```
root@dbs01 ~
$ ls -l lifecycle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root     24740243 Jun  4 20:48 lifecycle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This is after I copy the new copy of the original JAR file:

```
root@dbs01 ~
$ ls -l lifecycle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root     24833475 Jun  4 20:55 lifecycle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I then run the Java command:

```
root@dbs01 ~
$ java -cp lifecycle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.abc.lifecycle.cli.LifecycleManagerCli -dm web 0001 lm2-dom0.sfbay.abc.com ZONE /path/to/bits
Jun 4, 2009 8:55:51 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@186c6b2: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@186c6b2]; startup date [Thu Jun 04 20:55:51 GMT+00:00 2009]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 4, 2009 8:55:51 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [lifecycle_lite.xml]
Jun 4, 2009 8:55:51 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@186c6b2]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@88e2dd
Jun 4, 2009 8:55:51 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [lifecycle.properties]
Jun 4, 2009 8:55:51 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@88e2dd: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,com.abc.lifecycle.util.LoggingConfigurer#0,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,txAdvice,lifecycleOperations,org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0,dataSource,hibernateSessionFactory,moduleDefinitionDao,moduleHostDao,moduleInstanceDao,physicalHostDao,serviceDefinitionDao,serviceInstanceDao,numericOffsetDao,virtualHostDao,broker,jmsConnectionFactory,lifecycleMessageQueue,lifecycleMessageXmlConverter,lifecycleMessageListener,lifecycleMessageListenerContainer,jmsTemplate,lifecycleProcessor,statusChecker,lifecycleComponentBuilder,lifecycleManagerInitializer,lifecycleManagerCli]; root of factory hierarchy
Hibernate:
    insert
    into
        SERVICE_INSTANCE
        (CREATED_DATE, OPTIMISTIC_LOCKING_VERSION, UPDATED_DATE, MODULE_INSTANCE_ID, serviceDefinition_ENTITY_ID)
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate:
    delete
    from
        NUMERIC_OFFSET
    where
        ENTITY_ID=?
        and OPTIMISTIC_LOCKING_VERSION=?
Exception in thread "lifecycleMessageListenerContainer-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jms/support/JmsUtils
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.clearResources(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1024)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:887)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 3 more
```

At this point i kill it with Ctrl-C:

```
^CException in thread "ActiveMQ ShutdownHook" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/broker/TransportConnection$3
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.stopAsync(TransportConnection.java:920)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.stop(TransportConnection.java:902)
        at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceStopper.stop(ServiceStopper.java:41)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.stop(TransportConnector.java:270)
        at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.dispose(ServiceSupport.java:43)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory.stopped(VMTransportFactory.java:226)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:518)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.containerShutdown(BrokerService.java:1754)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService$4.run(BrokerService.java:1732)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$3
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 9 more
```

Then you can see that the JAR file has been changed:

```
root@dbs01 ~
$ ls -l lifecycle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root     24740243 Jun  4 20:56 lifecycle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I can find the JmsUtils class and the ActiveMQ TransportConnection class it is complaining about in my Maven repository, what else could I try?

```
root@dbs01 ~
$ jar tf lifecycle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep JmsUtils
org/springframework/jms/support/JmsUtils.class
root@dbs01 ~
$ jar tf lifecycle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep TransportConnection                                               
org/apache/activemq/broker/MapTransportConnectionStateRegister.class
org/apache/activemq/broker/SingleTransportConnectionStateRegister.class
org/apache/activemq/broker/TransportConnection$1.class
org/apache/activemq/broker/TransportConnection$2.class
org/apache/activemq/broker/TransportConnection$3.class
org/apache/activemq/broker/TransportConnection.class
org/apache/activemq/broker/TransportConnectionState.class
org/apache/activemq/broker/TransportConnectionStateRegister.class
org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/ManagedTransportConnection.class
```

What can be modifying the JAR file's state during execution?  What if I attach a debugger from a remote machine -- should this have any effect (I assume no)?

Thanks in advance.

--James

Answer (score 6):

First thing to try is change the mode on your jar file to `444` or even `400`, and see what blows up.

Java, the JRE itself, shouldn't be modifying the jar file at all; it only needs read access to it.  The most probable case is that something, somewhere, mistakenly is getting the jar file path for a data file path, God alone knows how.

Make the file read-only, and you should get an exception where the access (or at least the open) occurs.

Comment: Same thing happens when I make the file 444 or 400 permissions.  What gives -- how can the file be being written to when it's read only?

Comment: Don't run the application as root.